# Workflow does not wake up from delay activity in staging environment

Tags: 2010, workflow, workflow-activity

I have a custom SharePoint 2010 (made in visual studio) workflow that contains a delay activity within a while loop.

The workflow works fine in dev and test environments, but not i n the staging environment. There, it seems not to wake up from the delay activity. In one instance, a workflow managed to wake up, althoug much, much later than expected. Other instances started at rougly the same time, has not woken up.

After redeploying the solutions, we did a timer service restart and an iisreset. But, we did this only on the central admin server. Can this be the problem? Do I need to reset timer service on all servers? What about iisreset? Do I have to redeploy before I attempt to fix by restarting timer service? Should I terminate any running workflows first?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to resolve itself over night somehow.

Probably, either the "Workflow Auto Cleanup Job", "Workflow Failover Timer Job" or both had to run for the system to work properly again. It probably wouldn't hurt to do timer service restart and iisreset on all servers as well.